# how to use AJAX to get data from another website

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a website for personal use that gathers Coronavirus data. It will track the global percentage rate of people infected, total global cases, total United States cases, and total cases by state. As you know, getting data from all 50 states + territories every time I want to update it is a nightmare. I've learned that this is possible with AJAX. Only problem is, I don't know how to make the code to do that. Is this possible? If so, could you help me make the code?

EDIT: I wanted to grab the data using the id tag.
Here is the project on Github:

https://github.com/Codeer12/coronavirus-data

I'm trying to put it into something like that.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. fetch() is the easiest way usually. Do you have any example code that we can use as a scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data with ajax from API that you have with this code.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '[Your API]',
  type: '[GET | POST | ...]'
  success: function (response) {
    // Do something
  },
  error: function (xmlHttpReq) {
    console.error(xmlHttpReq);
  }
});
```

If you want to request the API in frontend, make sure your API server had solved CORS problem.

I'm not sure it helps or not. I need to know more detail.

Comment: Read the edit. Just to make sure you know there has been an edit :)